# visual studio not finding firebase node module

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-2013, npm, typescript, firebase

I used the command `npm install firebase --save` from the root of my project folder and a firebase folder was successfully added to my node_modules folder and the packages.json was also updated.

I also use typescript so I have a app.ts file where I try and do `import Firebase = require("firebase");`

However it doesn't work. I get red squiggles and error saying `cannot find external module "firebase"`.

I have installed express and importing it in app.ts as well and that works fine, no errors.

I have tried to look through the firebase source but its minified and impossible to try and do any finding there, about what is exported and such.

Any ideas about what might be wrong and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three things:

- You should download the Firebase type definition from Definitely Typed using NuGet, TSD, or some other method.
- The Firebase definition on Definitely Typed doesn't seem to be written in an external module form.  You may need to add the line `export = Firebase;` at the bottom of it.
- TypeScript currently has odd default behavior with definition files (d.ts) that describe external modules written in JavaScript; it will search in each directory from the directory where the file is back to the root of the current drive looking for a `.ts` or `.d.ts` file with a name that matches the name of the thing you've imported.  So your best bet is to move the `Firebase.d.ts` file to the root of the project.  If you're interested in a bit more discussion on this, check out https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2338 .  They're working on it.

If you do those three things, it should work.

Comment: Thank you! That did it. A bit embarrassed I forgot about the definition files. But point 2 and 3 were really helpful. To get it working I had to do a bit more actually. I looked at how the express.d.ts were set up and it had a module declared at the top level with the same name as the file and the export at the bottom of that module. When I did that with the firebase.d.ts it started working. Not optimal editing in those files though.. still thank you.